# You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. even using api key

Tags: geocoding

I am using google api to get latitude and longitude but hitting this url

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%223053%22&sensor=false&region=AU&key=<myKey>
```

gives me constantly this error

```
{
"error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.",
"results" : [],
"status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

Even it gave response 4 or 5 time but after that giving same error. Please help me with this. Thank You

Comment: Don't post API keys on the internet- then anyone can use them.

Comment: Maybe the error message can give you a hint: "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API"

Comment: @TobyU yes i know we can hit request 2500 times per day, but i dont think so it did request this much time